# What's the meaning of setting a power symmetric polynomial to a given value

Tags: polynomials, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I was reading [an involutive introduction to symmetric functions](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/%7Euvah099/Maths/Sym/SymFuncs2020.pdf) of Mark Wildon. In particular, I was trying to understand how to derive the derangements of $S_n$ with symmetric functions. In the book the result appears as Corollary $1.12$, which is the following:

> **Corollary 1.12**
>
> (i) *Let $d_n$ be the number of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$. Then*
> $$\frac{d_n}{n!} = 1 - \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} - \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}.$$
>
> (ii) *Let $O_n$ be the number of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$ that have an odd number of cycles, and let $E_n$ be the number of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$ that have an even number of cycles. Then $O_n - E_n = n-1$.*
>
> (iii) *Let $o_n$ be the number of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$ that are odd permutations, and let $e_n$ be the number of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$ that are even permutations. Then $o_n - e_n = (-1)^n(n-1)$.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $\mathcal{D}_n$ be the set of derangements in $\text{Sym}_n$. For (i) and (ii) specialize the version of the Cycle Index Formula in (8) by setting $p_1 = 0$ and $p_k = z$ for $z \geq 2$, where $z$ is an indeterminate. We get
>
> $$\exp \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{z t^k}{k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{D}_n} z^{\text{cyc}(\sigma)}$$
>
> where $\text{cyc}(\sigma)$ is the number of cycles in $\sigma$. Setting $z=1$ we get
>
> $$\frac{\exp(-t)}{1-t} = \exp \left ( -t - \log(1-t) \right ) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{d_n}{n!} t^n.$$
>
> Taking the coefficient of $t^n$ on the left hand side gives (i).
>
> ...

In particular I don't understand the meaning of setting $p_0 = 1$ and $p_k = z$ for $k \geq 2$. This should enclose the information of derangements but I don't see how, since I'm thinking to those as polynomials, I would have expected to evaluate $p_k$ in some value, such as $(1,\cdots,1)$ to get a "number" from the start, but this came after. Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think it shuold be motivated in order to understand what's incorrect in the question.

Comment: Don't care (btw, I have upvoted your question); your question is perfectly written. My comment is that there are many nice contributors on this site ; unfortunately there are a few who are harmful by their compulsive irrational downvoting.

Comment: I just included into your question the reference to the lecture notes. Sorry not to be able to answer it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, your comment is really appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't) so that future users have an easier time finding this question. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for the tip, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the cycle index formula the $p_i$ are a countable set of indeterminates, not the power symmetric polynomials. They can be specialized to the power symmetric polynomials and this is interesting to do for various reasons but they don't have to be. So there's no issue with specializing them to some other values, or other indeterminates, etc.

Said another way the cycle index formula is an identity of generating functions with coefficients in the ring of polynomials in countably many variables $p_i$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, wasn't clear to me. Why setting $p_0 = 1$ and $p_k = z$ for $k \geq 2$ encloses the information of derangements?

Comment: @jacopo: the cycle index formula is a generating function counting permutations by their cycle decompositions, where the exponent of $p_i$ counts the number of $i$-cycles. A derangement is a permutation with no fixed points, or equivalently $1$-cycles. So setting $p_1 = 0$ (you've switched the $0$ and the $1$ here) gives you the cycle indices of the derangements only. Then setting $p_k = z$ for $k \ge 2$ gives a generating function for derangements based on the total number of cycles, given by the exponent of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

We start with identity (1.9) from the paper
\begin{align*}
\exp\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{p_k}{k}t^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}
\sum_{\sigma\in\mathrm{Sym}_n}p_1^{\mathrm{cyc}_1(\sigma)}\cdots p_n^{\mathrm{cyc}_n(\sigma)}t^n\tag{1.9}
\end{align*}

- Setting $p_1=0$ (and not $p_0=1$) in the right-hand side of (1.9) means we do not count permutations with fixed points, leaving precisely the permutations in $\mathrm{Sym}_n$ which are derangements. The identity (1.9) reduces to
  \begin{align*}
  \exp\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{p_k}{k}t^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}
  \sum_{\color{blue}{\sigma\in D_n}}p_2^{\mathrm{cyc}_2(\sigma)}\cdots p_n^{\mathrm{cyc}_n(\sigma)}t^n\tag{2.1}
  \end{align*}
  where the left-hand side starts with $k=2$ and at the right-hand side we sum over all permutations which are derangements $\color{blue}{\sigma\in D_n}$.
- Since we just want to count the *number* of derangements we do simplifications in two steps. At first we simplify the expression (2.1) further by substituting each parameter $p_2,\ldots,p_n$ with $z$ which gives
  \begin{align*}
  \exp\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{z}{k}t^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}
  \sum_{\sigma\in D_n}z^{\mathrm{cyc}(\sigma)}t^n
  \end{align*}
  This way we do not any longer differentiate between different cycle lengths at the right-hand side. Furthermore it's now easy to get the wanted representation by letting $z=1$. Otherwise we would have to cope with substituting tuples $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ of different length at the left-hand side and at the right-hand side of (2.1) which is slightly more cumbersome.
- Setting now $z=1$ we have $\sum_{\sigma\in D_n}z^{\mathrm{cyc}(\sigma)}=d_n$. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\exp\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{n!}t^n}\tag{2.2}
  \end{align*}
  and some more simplifications of the left-hand side of (2.2) can follow.

Comment: I'm sorry I precisely do not understand the sentence "in the right-hand side of (1.9) means we do not count permutations with fixed points."

Comment: @jacopoburelli: The exponent in $p_k^{\mathrm{cyc}(\sigma)}$ gives the number of $k$-cycles in the permutation $\sigma$. The fixed points of a permutation are the cycles of length $1$. So, setting $p_1=0$ means we count only permutations with cycles of length $\geq 2$, i.e. permutations with no fixed points.